# Here's a Geeky Riddle

Tags: riddle

Riddle hints above, have fun :

> *I may be composed of letters and symbols but I'm not a word.*
>
> *I am silent but expressive and i generally represent feelings.*
>
> *If well arranged, i can represent anything.*
>
> *I am used almost everywhere.*

Comment: Short riddles often allow good interpretations and answers that were not intended, as is happening here. If there is some reason (beyond "that wasn't what I was thinking of") why the existing answers do not solve this riddle, it's not apparent at all what part of the riddle actually invalidates those responses. Because it seems they should be at least as valid as any other answer you might have in mind, this may be "too broad"—you may need to update the riddle to make sure invalid responses are demonstrably invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Potentially:

> An Emoticon? (Or "Emoji")

I may be composed of letters but I'm not a word.

> :p, :L etc contain letters, and not words.

I am silent but expressive.

> They usually represent expressions, and are certainly silent

If well put, i can represent anything.

> They have grown in number to the point almost any expression can be put across...

Comment: Emoticon $\uparrow$

Comment: @user477343 that's a symbol or a special character.

Comment: @AnouarBelkadi There was originally a comment above with an emoji. So I put the arrow to indicate where it was. Now the comment has... disappeared?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's what you're going for, but I think it might be

> A book

I may be composed of letters but I'm not a word.

> A book has many letters and indeed many words, not just one.

I am silent but expressive.

> Books don't make noise, but can be expressive in their descriptions.

If well put, i can represent anything.

> A well written book can convey any idea.

Comment: What if it was a picture book?

Answer (score 3):

The answer might be..

> .. a **story**.

I may be composed of letters but I'm not a word.

> A story is made up of letters and words, but isn't a word in itself.

I am silent but expressive.

> A story can be read silently.

If well put, i can represent anything.

> When written well, the story can be about anything in the world and beyond.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a variable or a function name?

I may be composed of letters but I'm not a word.

> It is made of letter (or alphanumeric) but it's not a word

I am silent but expressive.

> Because it is not a word it will be silent but still means something

If well put, i can represent anything.

> Yes, you can represent anything with a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

> ASCII ART

```
*               MMM8&&&            *
              MMMM88&&&&&    .
             MMMM88&&&&&&&
 *           MMM88&&&&&&&&
             MMM88&&&&&&&&
              MMM88&&&&&&
                MMM8&&&      *
      |\___/|
     =) ^Y^ (=            .              '
      \  ^  /
       )=*=(       *
      /     \
      |     |
     /| | | |\
     \| | | |/\
_/\_/\/ / \ \_ \/\_/\_/\_/\_/\_/\_/\_
|  |  |  |  | \_) |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
```

Comment: Wow... Just, wow... :O

Answer (score 1):

There's already an accepted answer, but I think this could also describe

> an equation.

I may be composed of letters but I'm not a word.

> An equation generally has variables represented by letters

I am silent but expressive.

> An equation is not a thing that makes a sound, but is used to express complex ideas

If well put, i can represent anything.

> Equations are used to describe everything from simple geometry to How the Universe Works

Comment: Well maybe, however i wrote "expressive" as emotional expressions. Good logic though.

Comment: @AnouarBelkadi well there is such thing as an *expression* in mathematics. It is exactly like an equation, but it has no equals sign.